# How to write the radcombobox selectedindexchange event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I don't know how to write the javascript function in radcombobox selectedIndexchange.

ASP.NET

```
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label73" CssClass="labels" Text="Call Response"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" Skin="Metro" ID="cbocallresponse" AutoPostBack="true" EmptyMessage="Select Call Response" ZIndex="100001">
<Items>
                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="Attended" Text="Attended" />
                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="NoAnswer" Text="NoAnswer" />
                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="CallBacklater" Text="CallBacklater" />
                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="Number does not exists" Text="Number does not exists" />
                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="Wrong Number" Text="Wrong Number" />
</Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
 <span class="warning">*</span>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" CssClass="warning" Text="Select call response" ControlToValidate="cbocallresponse" ValidationGroup="CallValidate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
</tr>
```

Vb.Net

```
Private Sub cbocallresponse_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles cbocallresponse.SelectedIndexChanged
        If cbocallresponse.SelectedValue = "CallBacklater" Then
            pnlSchedule.Visible = True
            popwindow(radcalllog)
        Else
            popwindow(radcalllog)
        End If
    End Sub
```

I want to write down the javascript function this selectedindexchange because i get every selectedindex its get postback.

Comment: <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" `OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="<client_event_name>"` Skin="Metro" ID="cbocallresponse" AutoPostBack="true" EmptyMessage="Select Call Response" ZIndex="100001">   Use this OnClientSelectedIndexChanged Attribute to trigger the assigned JS function.

Comment: i don't know how to write the SelectedIndexChanged in java script

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/events/onclientselectedindexchanged check out this Telerik doc... Let me know if you have any trouble on this...

Comment: i checked but how i convert this code to JS ` If cbocallresponse.SelectedValue = "CallBacklater" Then
            pnlSchedule.Visible = True
            popwindow(radcalllog)
        Else
            popwindow(radcalllog)
        End If`

Comment: what is radcalllog? can you show me?

Comment: radcalllog is PopUp window ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure about popupwindow here my solution is

```
  <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="cl_Indexchange" Skin="Metro" ID="cbocallresponse" AutoPostBack="true"
                                                        EmptyMessage="Select Call Response" ZIndex="100001">
                                                        <Items>
                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="Attended" Text="Attended" />
                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="NoAnswer" Text="NoAnswer" />
                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="CallBacklater" Text="CallBacklater" />
                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="Number does not exists" Text="Number does not exists" />
                                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="Wrong Number" Text="Wrong Number" />
                                                        </Items>
                                                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

into the `<script>` tag

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function cl_Indexchange(sender, eventArgs) {
            var pnl = document.getElementbyid("pnlSchedule");
            var item = eventArgs.get_item();
            if ( item.get_text() == "CallBacklater")

                 pnl.style.display="none";

               else
                 //if you what to make it visible
                  //pnl.style.display="block";
                  ....

        }
    </script>
```

hope this helps

Comment: just try add `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManger1" runat="Server" />`  in the form.